# Can i generate a table with two vectors?

Tags: r

There is table i want to generate:

```
y
160 165 170 175 180 185 
2   4   5   6   3   1
```

Can i generate `y` (the table) with following two vectors?

```
height<-c(160,165,170,175,180,185)
times<-c(2,4,5,6,3,1)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could just use `setNames`:

```
setNames(times, height)
# 160 165 170 175 180 185 
#   2   4   5   6   3   1
```

If you want to make sure its `class` is also `table`, wrap it in `as.table`:

```
as.table(setNames(times, height))
# 160 165 170 175 180 185 
#   2   4   5   6   3   1
```

Using the latter method would allow you to make use of some of the methods available for `table`. For instance, one that comes to mind is the `data.frame` method. Compare:

```
data.frame(setNames(times, height))
#     setNames.times..height.
# 160                       2
# 165                       4
# 170                       5
# 175                       6
# 180                       3
# 185                       1

data.frame(as.table(setNames(times, height)))
#   Var1 Freq
# 1  160    2
# 2  165    4
# 3  170    5
# 4  175    6
# 5  180    3
# 6  185    1
```

Answer (score 4):

One way it would be possible is the following:

```
table(rep(height, times))

160 165 170 175 180 185 
 2   4   5   6   3   1
```

where every element in height will be repeated by the element of the same index in times.